# My PDO Insert data not working

Tags: php, html, pdo

I wanted to do is to add the data I type in the inputs to the database but my current code wont work. I get this code from the tutorials I've watched in YouTube. My problem is its not adding the data I inputed to the database.

index.php

```
<?php 
require_once('header.php');
?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="index.php"> 
Name: <input type="text" id="name" name="name" /><br />
Age: <input type="text" id="age" name="age" /><br />
Address: <input type="text" id="address" name="address" /><br />
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="male" />Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="Female" />Female<br />
<input type="submit" value="Add" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

header.php:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = "test";

$dbc = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $host . ";dbaname=" . $db, $user, $pass);

if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $q = "INSERT INTO students(name, age, address, gender) VALUES(:name, :age, :address, :gender);";
    $query = $dbc->prepare($q);
    $results = $query->execute(array(
        ":name" => $name,
        ":age" => $age,
        ":address" => $address,
        ":gender" => $gender
    ));
}
?>
```

Comment: _I get this code from the tutorials I've watched in youtube._ - There's your problem, right there.

Comment: in the DSN: dbname=  not dbaname=

Comment: Where do you think it's breaking?  Are your variables getting to your PHP?  Are you connecting to your DB correctly?  Is the SQL query syntax correct?  Have you troubleshooted this at all?

Comment: Add `$dbc->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` before if statement and post error message if there is any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did some small cleanup here. Noticed an extant `;` at the end of the `INSERT INTO` query, so removed that. Also, using [`bindParam`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) instead of passing an array. This should work.

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])){

    $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : null;
    $age = isset($_POST['age']) ? $_POST['age'] : null;
    $address = isset($_POST['address']) ? $_POST['address'] : null;
    $gender = isset($_POST['gender']) ? $_POST['gender'] : null;

    $q = "INSERT INTO students(name, age, address, gender) VALUES(:name, :age, :address, :gender)";

    $query = $dbc->prepare($q);
    $query->bindParam(':name', $name);
    $query->bindParam(':age', $age);
    $query->bindParam(':address', $address);
    $query->bindParam(':gender', $gender);

    $results = $query->execute();

}
```

But looking at your code there are ways you can refine it even more:

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])){

    $q = "INSERT INTO students(name, age, address, gender) VALUES(:name, :age, :address, :gender)";

    $query = $dbc->prepare($q);

    // Set an array of post values.
    $post_array = array('name','age','address','gender');

    // Loop through the post values, set the string & then assign the string via bindParam.
    foreach ($post_array as $post_value) {
      $$post_value = isset($_POST[$post_value]) ? $_POST[$post_value] : null;
      $query->bindParam(':' . $post_value, $post_value);
    }

    $results = $query->execute();

}
```

The main refinement I did was to take all of the `$_POST` values & place them in an array. Then loop through that array and act on the values.